# How to update list items inside child components using Solid JS?

Tags: solid-js

I am new to Solid.js, and am not finding existing docs or Q/A to be very helpful.

I have a situation, which I'm sure is a common one, where I want to draw a list of objects as Components that will allow them to be edited. For example, lets say I have:

```js
let list_of_people = [
    {name:'Alice', age:20, address:{...} },
    {name:'Bob', age:22, address:{...} },
    ...
]
```

I want to draw these with a `<Person />` component that will allow name, age to be edited, and which will also include an `<Address />` component that will let whatever is going on in the .address property be edited too.

It's my understanding that the way to do this is:

```js
const [people,setPeople] = createStore(list_of_people); 
    // NB: Store instead of Signal because these are 
    // high-level objects with children and grandchildren.

function People(props){
    return <div>
        <For each={people}>{ (person,idx)=>{
            return <Person person={person} setPerson={???}/>
        } }</For>
    </div>
}

function Person(props){
    const person = props.person
    const setPerson = props.setPerson
    return < /*
        ... a bunch of HTML that can display the person's attributes  
        using {person} and set them using {setPerson}, and that also includes
        an <Address/> component that [address, setAddress] objects can be
        passed to.
    */ >
}
```

But, obviously, setPerson doesn't exist. How can I create it?

setPeople would allow me to get what I want by providing a path from the top-level 'parent' list. But I don't want to have to think about that from within the Person component - the whole point of using a component was to encapsulate that kind of concern away.

I can cheat by doing:

```js
<For each={people}>{ (_person,idx)=>{
    const [person, setPerson] = createStore( _person ); 
    // or createStore(people[idx]) or whatever
    return <Person person={person} setPerson={setPerson}/>
} }</For>
```

This seems hacky and I have no idea what it does regarding references and memory allocations and the like - ie, whether it would be "safe" if I were to have an object with hundreds of nested subobjects, and I wanted to do this trick for the <Components/> of each of them at every level.

I would like to know how the Solid.js devs intended us to solve these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If state lives inside the parent component, the only way to update the state from child components is passing the setter function down to the child components as a prop. There are alternatives though, which I will discuss at the end.

You can pass the whole function or create another function that uses the setter internally.

If I understand you correctly you are not happy with passing around `setPeople` as a whole because `Person` has to set `name` and `age` only, proving some form of encapsulation. So, you need to take the second option.

Here, `updatePerson` function takes name and age as parameter and update the list using `setPeople`:

```js
const updatePerson = (index: number, name: string, age: string) => {
    setPeople(data => {
      const updated = data.map((item, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          return {...item, name, age};
        }
        return item;
      });
      return [...updated];
    });
  }
```

Now you can pass the `updatePerson` function to the `Person` component:

```
<Person name={item.name} age={item.age} updatePerson={updatePerson} />
```

If you need only the update functionality, that will work, but if you need to add and remove people inside children, you have to provide additional setters.

Component are there to orginize code, and encapsulation if it keeps an internal state but you need to be more careful about establishing boundaries. The article Thinking in React may help you with that:

https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react

The article uses React but same rules apply for Solid too.

> This seems hacky and I have no idea what it does regarding references and memory allocations.

Since you are passing the same function, `updatePerson`, down to each item, there is no extra memory allocation.

Using functions for isolating and controlling inputs are not hacky, it is how you do it any programming language.

A Solid component compiles to function calls that uses native DOM elements. If you are not creating cyclic references there is no problem with nesting components. Plus you can take advantage on onCleanup hook to clean after components when they are unloaded.

If you are not using very large data set, performance will not be a problem. If you are going to use large data set, you will have the same problem even if you use vanilla JavaScript. In that case you have to use some trickery like caching and virtualization.

Now, about the alternative methods in case you don't want to pass props down to child components.

1. You can use JavaScript scopes to access the state directly from the child component. You need to make sure the child component have access to the scope the data lives in.

You have to options:

- You can extract the data store into outer scope where child component can access it.
- Keep both the state and the child component inside the parent component.

Unlike React components, Solid components can access to their outer scopes.

2. Provide data through Context Provider and access the data inside the Child component through `useContext` API.

https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest#createcontext

PS: I see you are still confused. Let me explain briefly.

First and foremost, using a store or a signal makes no difference since stores use a signal internally. Stores offers some convinces. I will use a signal for simplicity.

Since data flows from parent to the children, there is no need to create additional signal inside `Person` component. When we update the data that is kept on the list, it will be updated everywhere. If you use additional signal to keep an item's property, you need to propagate changes to the original list, list that is kept inside the parent component. So, it will introduce an unnecessary overhead.

I used `updateName` to update the name field only, in order to simplify the logic. You can use multiple fields, but since you can not update two input fields at the same time because you can edit one input field at a time, so having multiple fields serves no purpose here.

Can you see the unidirectional data flow. Calling updateName sets a new value for the people signal and the data trickles down to the child components.

Lastly, I used Index, to keep the input field focused while editing. If you use For, you will lose focus while updating the element. That is because For renders a new DOM element when object reference for an item changes. Buy running updateName, we are creating a new element. Index uses the previously rendered element, but updates the innerText values.

https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/b315a4e5-ff2e-45bb-93db-dc7dbfab0ce3

```js
import { Component, createSignal, For, Index, JSX } from "solid-js"

const Person: Component<{
  id: number;
  name: string,
  age: number,
  updateName: (index: number, name: string) => void
}> = (props) => {
  const handleChange: JSX.EventHandlerUnion<HTMLInputElement, Event> = (event) => {
    props.updateName(props.id, event.currentTarget.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Name: {props.name} Age: {props.age}</div>
      <div>Update Name: <input onInput={handleChange} value={props.name}></input></div>
    </div>
  )
}

interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: { city: string },
};

export const App = () => {
  const initial: Array<Person> = [
    { name: 'John Doe', age: 20, address: { city: 'LA' } },
    { name: 'Jenny Doe', age: 40, address: { city: 'NY' } },
  ];

  const [people, setPeople] = createSignal<Array<Person>>(initial);

  const updateName = (index: number, name: string) => {
    setPeople(prev => {
      const updated = prev.map((el, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          return { ...el, name };
        }
        return el;
      });
      return [...updated];
    });
  }

  return (
     <Index each={people()}>
      {(item, index) => (
        <Person
          id={index}
          name={item().name}
          age={item().age}
          updateName={updateName}
        />
      )}
    </Index>
  )
};
```

Comment: You say "Component are there to provide isolation and encapsulation but you need to be more careful about establishing boundaries." The <Person/> component is there to display any 'person' object. It might be used elsewhere to display a person who doesn't live in the 'people' list. How else are you supposed to draw the boundary there? All my intuition says that a 'person' component should only need to know about the 'person' object itself.

Comment: Also, this solution forces me to already know what's in a person object so I can construct this custom updater function each time. This feels stringier than just creating a new Store each time as I was doing. Are there performance concerns with just doing what I was doing?

Comment: > "this solution forces me to already know what's in a person object so I can construct this custom updater function each time." You get the component state for Person from outside, which forces you to use an external setter if you yant to update the data from the inside of Person. You can't update this external data directly like you do with JS objects. Using setters may incur  performance penalty due to additional indirection but it is negligible. Plus it better this way because of unidirectional data flow.

Comment: @Tim, Components can provide encapsulation if they keep an internal state, clarified it. I was trying to emphesize that you slice a list item into two objects, person and address which may complicate things if you need to add and remove items. By complicate i mean you need to create multiple setters. You could keep name, age and address together.  You dont need additional store in Person, becase it serves no purpose.

Comment: If my approach is okay, then I think I prefer it. It feels conceptually simpler to me to always pass in a new Store than to stop and create a custom function every single time. I understand the difference between getters and setters, and I understand that if the object does in fact need to affect external data (for eg, by removing itself from an external list on click of a "delete" btn) then extra fns need to be passed in. I assumed that, if what I'm doing was intended usage, there would be a utility function for it already. Apparently not. But as long as it does no harm, I'll keep doing it.

Comment: Also, why have the strings <Person/> and <Address/> been edited out of my question? Without those, there's no context for the repeated word "component" - that's exactly the kind of thing that would make my eyes glaze over if I were on the outside trying to read it. Not that it matters, I suppose, if I've already got my answer.

Comment: People tend to clarify questions if the intent is not clear. Maybe components are edited out in one of those edits. I improve the answer with a working example. You need to keep the data flow clean, It will be more performant and more maintainable.